# jQuery simple loading and unloading content into DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-load

I know this question has been asked before but I cannot get the answer I need so I'm going to try to simplify it:

When I click on .LINK, I want the #GRID content to be filled with other divs, so I'm using*:

```
$(".LINK").click(function(){
    $( "#GRID" ).load('my_linked_file.html .other_divs');
});
```

So far so good. But now I have a second link, that I want to use to 'revert' this loaded content, to go back to it's original state. I'm just doing the same all over again, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(".LINK2").click(function(){
    $( "#GRID" ).load('my_original_file.html .my_original_divs');
});
```

I'd be happy to upload a jsfiddle but .load only works on the server. I can upload a jsfiddle for illustration (layout) purposes if that helps?

(*I've seen many people suggesting the hide and show method. But I have plenty of links with plenty of content and I'm assuming doing so will slow down my page quite noticeably)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this worked for me:

```
<a href="my_linked_file.html" class="LINK">Click Me</a>
<a href="my_original_file.html" class="LINK2">Click Me 2</a>
<div id="GRID"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.LINK').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#GRID').load($(this).attr('href') + ' .other_divs');
});
$('.LINK2').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#GRID').load($(this).attr('href') + ' .original_divs');
});
</script>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, until I try to add it to a link which is INSIDE the DIV. Like this: <div id="GRID">
   <div class="thumbs" id="two">
 <a href="project_sample.html">THIS LINK INSTEAD</a>
</div> So when the link the associated to the function is outside the GRID div is fine, but if it's a child of it, then it won't work. Do you know how to fix this? Thank you so much

Comment: is that link to "project_sample.html" going to be of LINK or LINK2 class? If you intended to put that in your comment, it still works for me: <div id="GRID"><div class="thumbs" id="two"><a href="project_sample.html" class="LINK">THIS LINK HAS A CLASS</a></div></div>. I added that to the original document, and it had the desired results. Then I added it to the content that is loaded through jQuery functions from the main page, and the link still targeted the div#GRID as it should.

Comment: JrAnderson- This is almost there, thank you! It works, but it only works once. If I click on link, it loads the .other_divs perfectly. Then I click on LINK2 and it goes back to the .original_divs. Perfect. But if I click again on LINK, it does not run the preventDefault and loads the full my_linked_file.html  Any idea why this might be happening? Here's a jsfiddle so you can see the code.http://jsfiddle.net/m/nfu/ Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can this help?;

```
$( "#GRID" ).html('').load('my_original_file.html .my_original_divs');
```

Comment: I don't know if it's because the .LINK2 button has an added toggle functionality but it won't work :(

Comment: try to preventDefault() and stopPropagation() on .LINK2 click and see if is that...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the last function to:

```
$('.LINK2').delegate("a", "click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

 $('#Grid').load($(this).attr('href') + ' .thumbs');

});
```